# Partialy Hiding PII in a View

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some columns with PII that I need to share with a coworker. They need to be able to see 50% of the characters and the other 50% should be replaced by Asterisks, but I dont know how to do it.

Also, would you use a table or a view to do this? Do you have any advice? I'm pretty new in SQL.

So far, my code is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
client_id INT NOT NULL,
mail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
phone INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);

INSERT INTO clients VALUES 
(1,'player_1@gmail.com',23234123),
(2,'player_2@outlook.com',23235543),
(3,'player_3@hotmail.com',343435523);

CREATE VIEW clients_partial as (
SELECT client_id,
mail as mail_partial, #### PROBLEM TO SOLVE  
phone as phone_partial ### PROBLEM TO SOLVE
FROM clients);

SELECT * FROM clients_partial
```

What I have in clients_partial:
[image]

What I need in clients_partial:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not completely identical, but to anonymize it should be good

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
client_id INT NOT NULL,
mail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
phone INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);

INSERT INTO clients VALUES 
(1,'player_1@gmail.com',23234123),
(2,'player_2@outlook.com',23235543),
(3,'player_3@hotmail.com',343435523);

CREATE VIEW clients_partial as (
SELECT client_id
  ,
CONCAT(
concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mail,'@', 1),'@'
  ,LEFT(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(mail,'@', -1)
  ,1))
  ,  CONCAT(LEFT(
  Right(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mail,'@', -1),length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mail,'@', -1))  -1)
  ,-length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mail,'@', -1))  -1),
  REPEAT('*', 
  length(
  Right(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(mail,'@', -1)
  ,length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mail,'@', -1))  -1
  )
  ) -1))
  ) as mail_partial, #### PROBLEM TO SOLVE  
concat(left(phone,length(phone) -4),'****') as phone_partial ### PROBLEM TO SOLVE
FROM clients
  );

SELECT * FROM clients_partial
```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

| client_id | mail_partial | phone_partial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | player_1@g******* | 2323**** |
| 2 | player_2@o********* | 2323**** |
| 3 | player_3@h********* | 34343**** |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bUXamSAm)

Answer (score -2):

Determine length of string
Extract first xx characters
Pad that with asterisks to the length of the string

```
 // show first xx chars of string padded with asterisk to length of string
 $str = "Hello World this is a versy long string that is very long";
 $strlength = strlen($str); // get the length of the string
 $str = substr($str, 0,10); // shorten it to 10 characters starting from beginning
 $newstr =  str_pad($str,$strlength,"*"); // show first 10 characters, then * until length of original string
```

Adjust as needed.